# How to write tests using the service scope

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

My app is accessing object from the service scope (`package:gcloud/service_scope.dart`), like the `storageService` and additional services that I put inside the scope with `ss.register()`.

Now I want to unit test a function that accesses this scope, and uses mock objects that I want to put in the service scope.

Is the only way to do so, to register them for every test, like this:

```
var withServiceScope = (callback()) => ss.fork(() {
  // Register all services here
  return callback();
});
test('the description', () => withServiceScope(() async {
  // Call my function that can now access the service scope
}));
```

Or is there are way that allows me to do that in the `setUp()` function so I don't need to add this line for each test?

Comment: How is this related to google-app-engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might make it simpler to write your tests (code not tested)

```
import 'package:test/test.dart' as t;
import 'package:test/test.dart' show group;

var withServiceScope = (callback()) => ss.fork(() {
  // Register all services here
  return callback();
});

test(String description, Function testFunction) {
  t.test(description, () => withServiceScope(() async {
    testFunction();
  }));
}

main() {    
  test('the description', () async {
    // Call my function that can now access the service scope
  }));
}
```